# Rotating black hole

Tags: black-holes, angular-momentum, astrophysics, event-horizon, accretion-disk

I know that everything that is shaped from gravity force is rotating, and gravity is a central force. but I want to know how can we detect that a black hole has an angular momentum? By which experimental sign from the black hole?

Comment: Perhaps the accretion disk surrounding the black hole will provide some insight in to the properties of the black hole. See: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/109993/angular-momentum-of-a-black-hole

Comment: Not by the redshift of the background stars: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/457995

Answer (score 0):

A rotating black hole drags spacetime outside the event horizon and so a gas emitting light close to the event horizon  has redshifted light on one side of the event horizon and blueshifted light on the other

Comment: This would be true whether the black hole was rotating or not or even in Newtonian gravity.